# Which method is faster and better?

Tags: javascript, optimization

```
function toZero1(t) {
    return ("" + t).length < 2 ? "0" + ("" + t) : ("" + t);
}

function toZero2(t) {
    return "00".slice(("" + t).length) + ("" + t);
}
```

These functions do:
"6"-> "06"
"11"-> "11"
etc.

Comment: The one that's more legible.

Comment: I find the first one to be more readable, however, is this function called that often that it requires optimization? If the code is working, i think you are better of putting it on codereview than here though, this question is in the current form to broad for SO imho

Comment: As @Icepickle said, first one is more readable.

Comment: Method #3: `("00" + t).substr(-2, 2)` (assuming the length of the input string never exceeds 2). Aside: the first method will convert an empty string to a single `0`.

Comment: Or simply: `("00" + t).slice(-2)`